# How can i merge 4*4 cell array to form 1 256*256 cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell

I had a 256*256 matrix(Basically i did DNA operation on an image).I splitted them into 4*4 cell array for doing certain operation.Now i want to recombine them to form a 256*256 cell?How can I do that in MATLAB

```
a=imread('cameraman.tif');
for i=1:1:256
for j=1:1:256
    b{i,j,1} = dec2bin(a1(i,j),8);
end
end 

 plaintext_dna = bin2DNA(b);
 size(plaintext_dna);

K=4;
c=K*ones(256/4, 1);
small_mat=mat2cell(plaintext_dna,c',c');
% merge small_mat to get back  plaintext_dna........
function [ DNA_matrix] = bin2DNA( bin_matrix )

codebook = containers.Map({'00','11','10','01'},{'A','T','G','C'}); %// Lookup
outputCell = cellfun(@(x) values(codebook, {x(1:2),x(3:4),x(5:6),x(7:8)}), ...
         bin_matrix, 'uni', 0);
DNA_matrix = cellfun(@cell2mat, outputCell, 'uni', 0);

end
```

Comment: How did you split the original cell array? Can you show us your code and an example on, say, an 8*8 example?

Comment: Do **NOT** add code in comments. This was asked you 11 hours ago, so please *read*  that one and *edit*  your question.

Comment: @Adriaan editted now.Thanks

Comment: Woa, so much cells. Just use matrices instead of cell, that'd make your life so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

After you edited example (and I assumed `a1` meant `a`), I got 256 times 256 cell array `plaintext_dna` and 64 times 64 array of 4 by 4 cell arrays `small_mat`. To combine `small_mat` into array equivalent to `plaintext_dna`, I did following:

```
cols = size(small_mat,2);
reconstructed = cell(1, cols);
for n=1:cols
    reconstructed{n} = cat(1,small_mat{:,n});
end    
reconstructed = cat(2,reconstructed{:});
```

Afterwards `strcmp` between plaintext and reconstructed showed contents to be equal.

Comment: What output does `cell2mat` give

Comment: it says Input arguments, D1 through D2, must sum to each dimension of the input
matrix size, [64  64]

Comment: @unskillesMatlabist i editted my question.After converting that dna matrix to small cell i added that to another dna cell of same size(4*4).and finally i want to reconstruct 256*256 matrix